# How can I embed a public instagram feed in my application using oembed read api?

Tags: facebook, instagram, instagram-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.2

I have Instagram handles of the users and want to show their Instagram feed (if it is public) when they login into our application. I have my FB app reviewed for **oembed read**. But when I try to use the oembed_page API endpoint with an access token for getting Instagram page details it is showing the following error.
Note: I am trying it in FB graph API explorer- https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

Sample Url I tried:-
https://graph.facebook.com/oembed_page?url=https://www.instagram.com/instagram&access_token=_accesstoken_

Error:
"error": {
"message": "(#100) Invalid parameter",
"type": "OAuthException",
"code": 100
}

My aim is to get a user's all insta posts using an API call. Is there any endpoint which provide such a response?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/oembed-page is part of the "normal" Graph API documentation - so I would assume that only works for Facebook pages, not Instagram pages.

Comment: For IG, I think you can only oembed specific posts, not complete pages - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram/oembed

Comment: so there is no way to get instagram posts of a public page?I also found this API https://www.instagram.com/instagram/?__a=1     This returns some details ,links and images, but when tried to show them in my application It is showing cross-origin error.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.